# How to display github emoji codes in Mac Terminal?

Tags: mac, terminal.app

I want to display emoji codes from http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/ (e.g. `:+1:` ) inside github commit messages when doing `git log`. I use Mac Terminal app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use some kind of parser, like this one: https://github.com/as-cii/terminal-emojify

```
git log | emojify
```